# Parsing through an Array For Next loop Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am stuck here. Spent hours trying many different approaches but nothing is working

I have an array that holds text that looks like this

```
4456|4450|17
4466|4430|18
4446|4420|19
4436|4410|20
```

The separator is a pica ("|").

What I am trying to do is run through the array and extract the first two columns in separate strings to compare the values, look for the max, and min.

I am trying to end up with a string like this

```
4456,4466,4446,4436
```

Here is the solution:

```
                Dim source As String = prices
                Dim stringSeparators() As String = {vbCrLf}
                Dim result() As String
                result = source.Split(stringSeparators,
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

                Dim fString As String = String.Join(Of String)(", ", result.Cast(Of String).Select(Of String)(Function(x) x.Split("|")(0)))

                    MsgBox(fString)
```

Comment: The example you show and your current output doesn't add up. Either your array is wrong or you are getting the wrong values. For example should the first array be 4456|4450|17 or 4456, 4466, 4446, 4436. Also show how this array is populated. I can help but you may be putting these in wrong and I could explain that as well. More than likely you would want a List Of to hold your strings...

Comment: Not sure how to post a screen shot here, but the array is exactly as I show it. For some reason, the For Next loop is parsing every character individually. I have no idea why

Comment: What is highs1? Are you sure it's an array as well?

Comment: Is this vb.net or vb6? It can't be both. Please edit your question to remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Comment: @user6096423 I have solution for you here soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take your example below...

```
4456|4450|17
4466|4430|18
4446|4420|19
4436|4410|20

 prices = [the array shown above]
                For Each i As String In prices
                    high = (i.Split("|"))(0)
                    highs = highs & highs1 & ","

                    MsgBox(highs)
                Next
```

The reason you are getting `4,4,5,6,,4,4,5,0,,1,7` is because for each string you are splitting on the `|` and then **taking the first character** adding a comma to it.

If you want to get the first column or index whatever you want to call it before the `|` you need to loop through each string in that array and select out the values...

```
'this is my test array...
Dim arr As New ArrayList From {"4456|4450|17", "4466|4430|18", "4446|4420|19", "4436|4410|20"}
```

Now we can use a `String.Join` function, cast the array for each item as a string and finally select the first item on the split. This will get every item before the `|` and put them in a string separated with a comma.

```
 Dim fString As String = String.Join(Of String)(", ", arr.Cast(Of String).Select(Of String)(Function(x) x.Split("|")(0)))
```

If you want the second section select the 1st index as arrays start at 0...

```
 Dim sString As String = String.Join(Of String)(", ", arr.Cast(Of String).Select(Of String)(Function(x) x.Split("|")(1)))
```

Here is my screenshot of the outputs...

[image]